# How can I make a SWT table's cell editable in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: swt, cell, rcp

My question is that I have a SWT Table in Eclipse RCP project. I want its cells to be editable when I desire. How can I achieve such a functionality in Eclipse RCP, suggest me. Or, can we achieve exactly this functionality with JFace, Nebula Table controls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. Please have a look at the following snippets:

- SWT Snippet: [edit the text of a table item (in place)](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet88.java?view=co)
- JFace Snippet: [Snippet88](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet88.java) - Demonstrates different CellEditor-Types in one COLUMN with 3.3-API of JFace-Viewers

Hope these examples are useful to you..

Comment: thank you nonty for that preety URLs which i found helpful for me as you expected.

Comment: The snippets are in Git now: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet88.java

Comment: @FelixM Thanked. Updated.